# Proxy for a trigonometric angle function

Tags: mathematics

You can't calculate an actual/real angle with the sine function with discrete market data.

I need a substitute value for inputs that require an angle value.

If you're only calculating the angle between two adjacent bars, is it possible to use the distance formula as a proxy (x=1)?

Distance between two points:

c = SquareRoot((Xa-Xb)^2 + (Ya-Yb)^2);

c =distance

X=interval (time) = 1

Y=price

Distance between two points

http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Comment: What are you trying to measure?

Comment: @chrisaycock Time based financial calculation that requires a slope calculation are suspect.
I'm looking for a stable/robust representation for the slope component of the slope-intercept form.
Angle calculations using market data are nefarious to work with, as market compression rescales nonlinear.  I'm working with the Hurst exponent, it utilizes the slope-intercept form to characterize the market.

Comment: @chrisaycock   I need a function that will capture the estimation of the Hurst exponent without using the linear regression slope calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't compute angle between points, but between vectors. If you want a proxy for a cos of the angle between vectors (x1, y1), (x2, y2), take their dot product x1 * x2 + y1 * y2. This has nothing to do with quantitative finance.

Comment: tks, and I was thinking that this might be the wrong forum for this Q. I don't see that I have control over deleting my post.